# Script is not showing the searched image from the given folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, search

i have a list of images in my server folder which i need to show in a list format 
Now Iam trying to implement a search bar that helps to search the desired image by their filename.
.

This is my code i want to search an image from the list of images in my folder but it doesn't work .... please help to give the searched image from the list of images.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
div.gallery {
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px; /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gallery">
```

here is where the searching is done..

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ul id="myUL">   
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
$files = glob("patient_log/".$id."/*.*");
for ($i=0; $i<count($files); ++$i)

{
$image = $files[$i];
$info = pathinfo($image);
$file_name =  basename($image,'.'.$info);
echo ' 
<li><a href="#"><img src="'.$image .'">'.$file_name.'</a></li></br>';
}

?> 
</ul>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update your question to be more specific like what is actually not working, like is the PHP not listing them or is the javascript not searching them.

Comment: `glob("patient_log/".$id."/*.*")` is quite insecure